# how to use MobileIron AppConnect SDK in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobileiron

> Actually one of my client need to integrate MobileIron AppConnect sdk.
>   I have read all document on his website but I can’t understand how to
>   integrate. Please Help me any know about.

Comment: Did you enrol as developer on https://info.mobileiron.com/developer_portal_access_request_form_agreement_reg.html ?

Comment: i have one mobileiron Account 

AccountType : Developer Prospect.

Comment: Also i have downloaded "AppConnectiOSSDK_V4_1_1_12"